# Turn off OctoPrint server after starting print from SD card

Tags: octoprint, sd

I have OctoPrint set up on a Raspberry Pi (OctoPi). I have loaded a number of G-code files to the SD card on the printer.

My question is: If I initiate a print from the SD card via OctoPrint, can I then turn off the RPi so I can use it for other things while the print continues?

Answer (score 3):

Your printer will stop printing. So no.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnecting the USB or connecting it triggers a reboot in the printer. As a result, you can not disconnect or turn off the print server running OctoPrint.